# Analytical Badge - Can this be marked "(Retired)" or something?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, information-display

After seeing the Analytical badge, I visited every page in the FAQ.  I waited a few days, then came here to see if I could find any questions about why it never showed up in my profile.  It was then that I read that the badge was no longer working as of June 2013 (I must have missed this by DAYS, darn it!) due to the Help page restructure.

Since the badge is no longer being awarded in the future, but has been awarded in the past, maybe a designation of "(Retired)" next to it might eliminate some confusion?  I think there's another badge that was only given out in Beta that probably deserves that designation as well.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: Why not update the badge to make it work for the new help center then?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII That would be the sensible thing to do.

Comment: It's no longer possible to get the beta badge, yet it has no designation of being retired...

Comment: And it never was possible to earn a 'Precognitive'. No designation there either.

Comment: Exactly why I think the designation should exist, Lynn.

Comment: I guess I'd prefer to see the badge-awarding mechanism fixed for that particular badge, then let the documentation do the rest: [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for)

Comment: Related: [Shouldn't the Beta badge be retired like the Analytical badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197173/335251) (Answer: No, because it can still be earned on other new sites as they are created.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

At this time, we have no plans to revive the analytical badge.  The new help center has so many pages that requiring people to visit every one of them is not likely to encourage them to read.

We tossed around other ideas, but since we rolled out the new /about pages, having people read the help section comprehensively just isn't a goal anymore.

We are going to add (retired) to the description

Comment: I would prefer to make the badge awarded for spending 30 seconds and scrolling to the bottom of /about. At least it encourages people to read about basic site usage. So what if everyone gets the badge.

Comment: Crap, sorry I was uninformed. That badge is already "Informed". Yeah, I agree, do away with "Analytical".

Comment: Why not just delete the badge?

Comment: @Mistu4u It is still hanging around on people's user cards.

Comment: Ah, that's right.

Comment: If it's retired like 5-6 months ago, then why are people still getting the badge? http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1306/analytical I also tried reading the entire "Help" section but it's not awarding it to me.

Comment: @puretppc when a user gets merged, most badges don't move from the merge victim to the master, because it's easier for us to let the badges get re-awarded than it is to ensure a user shouldn't have a badge twice.  Such is the case with those recent awards.  The victims all had the Analytical badge, but the master user didn't.  When they were merged, the underlying "you visited the FAQ" history was moved, but the badge wasn't.  Next badge grant scheduled task then re-awarded.