# Shouldn't the Beta badge be retired like the Analytical badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, analytical-badge, beta-badge

On Stack Overflow, the [Analytical badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1306/analytical) was retired when the help center rolled out. However, although the site is long out of beta, the [Beta badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/30/beta) is still on the [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Shouldn't the Beta badge be retired the same way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly. The Beta badge can still be awarded on *other sites* (as they're created), just not *this* site. The difference between the Beta badge and the Analytical badge is that the features required to award the Analytical badge no longer exist, anywhere, and it is not possible to gain the Analytical badge *at all* now. Theoretically, it would make sense to just remove the badge, but rather than take away a bunch of bronze badges, they opted to just label it as retired and let users keep it.

Comment: I understand it's possible to earn the badge on other SE sites, but why couldn't it be retired on SO only?

Comment: @Mooseman Because it's not retired. The Beta process still exists, you just can't participate in it on Stack Overflow anymore. If the Beta process were completely gotten rid of, *then* it would make sense to retire the badge, since the features that relate to the badge would no longer exist.

Comment: Think of it like the job market. You work at one job for 5 years, and they lay you off to cut costs. You're not *retired*, but you can't go back to work for that same company either. You need to get a new job. -- The Beta badge isn't retired, you just need to go to a different site to get it.

Comment: @animuson even if the beta process were no longer relevant, I would still like to keep that beta badge, especially on Stack Overflow, as some kind of "badge of honor" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely true.  The Analytical badge was retired when I [made this suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185065/analytical-badge-can-this-be-marked-retired-or-something).  I also requested other badges be marked as Retired as well (i.e. the Precognitive badge, as it's no longer possible to earn it). Only the Analytical badge was marked as Retired as a result of that post.