# Visited every section of the FAQ (retired)

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, badges

The way to earn the 'Analytical' badge is: Visited every section of the FAQ (retired). What does (retired) mean? Does it mean that it is no longer available?

Comment: let the tag enjoy its retirement...

Answer (score 13):

It means that [the badge is no longer being awarded.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185069/133242)

See also *[List of all badges with full descriptions: Other badges.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188733/133242)*

Comment: I think that is a weird way to express the meaning. I prefer the straight way like "no more awarded" instead